# Using "packed" to convey cloudy

Tags: word-usage, american-english

> The sky is packed

Is it correct English? The intention is to convey that it's very cloudy outside

Comment: The grammar is good, but nobody will know what the sky is packed with. We'll probably guess aircraft first.

Comment: I would not guess aircraft or anything at all. I would ask you to rephrase the idea.

Comment: A place packed with people is crowded, not clouded. An overcast sky's full of clouds.

Answer (score 2):

> The intention is to convey that it's very cloudy outside

We wouldn't use *packed*, no.

We might say:

- The sky is cloudy
- The sky is overcast
- The skies are darkening
- The sky is ominous